# Android test of SharedPreferences failing on one device/OS version

Tags: android, testing

I have a ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 for an activity.

It it, I test that changes to settings are saved when the Activity is exited by the BACK key, in the onStop() method.

In my test, I start the activity, modify the settings, and then stop the activity with finish().
I wait for the activity to end, and then I check the settings saved in SharedPreferences.

In a Nexus 7 with Android 4.3 this test never fails.

In a Samsung S3 with Android 4.1.2 it fails always.

I have tried using different Contexts, and also using commit() instead of apply() in the SharedPreferences.Editor, with no difference in behaviour.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ending the activity with:

activity.finish();

you should end it with:

getInstrumentation().callActivityOnStop(activity);

I suspect there maybe a better way to end the activity and wait for it to exit, as if the Back key had been pressed and onStop() then called.

---

That "fix" has fixed the failing cases, but caused others to now fail. 
They only seem to work if I use activity.finish().